# Retrieve Speed Type Vs Speed Category

Tags: here-api

Hi I am able to retrace the Speed Category from the Geocode api, how do I retrieve speed type which will provide actual road speed of a given location on a road

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that the LinkInfoType of the Geocoder is deprecated and should not be used any longer. The Fleet Telematics Advanced Data Sets would be the right service to request these kind of details:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/topics/quick-start-view-map-data.html

Comment: No the output showing in the link provided shows speed category not speed type. As indicated in my initial question I am needing the speed type output as they shows the actual speed limit of road itself rather the the speed category which provides a code they represents a speed range